Display community page as a modal or popup in Lightning community
In the below image, there is a hyperlink formula field 'Favourite' clicking on which I need to open a community page as a modal or popup in lightning community but it's redirecting to the next page.

In this community page, I've embedded a screen flow to which I'm passing Record Id from the hyperlink formula field. Can you please help to open this community page as a modal instead of redirecting to the next page ?
              **Favourite Hyperlink formula field**

HYPERLINK('/portal/s/markfav?SFrecordId='&Id,'Add Fav','_self')
where markfav is the community page in which screen flow is embedded.
I've already tried all the other possible ways like VF Page, Lightning components etc. but it didn't work for me.
Can you please help me here ? I'm totally stucked at this point.
Or is there any other workaround also ? Please suggest.
